# how to show View for certain IP Addresses and logged user?

Tags: drupal-6, ip-address, drupal-views

How can I show a View for certain visitors from a specific IP address or specific logged in user? The view should only display for a visitor from a specific IP address,and other visitors see an empty View.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use the [Restrict Login or Role Access by IP Address](http://drupal.org/project/restrict_by_ip) module to assign the specific IP address(es) a role. Then in the view, configure *Basic settings > Access* to limit access to the view to only users with that particular role.

Comment: No,this module work for 1 user,and user logged.i want for each anonymous user.

Comment: In that case, how about the ipAuthenticator module instead? http://drupal.org/project/ipAuthenticator